# PHP is not throwing exception, only responding with 500

Tags: php, exception

Response status code is 500 but I get blank screen with no information on it. Is this normal?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
throw new Exception('php is awesome :|');
```

Comment: No, it isn't normal to get a 500 response, not for the code you've posted.... check your code with a `php -l` syntax check from the command line

Comment: @Cthulhu Wanna answer it so I can accept? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors are being written to logs but not displayed. Execute the following to see them in the browser:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Comment: +1 from me too. Maybe downvoter thought it was too basic?? Dunno.

Comment: I guess it's just  that haters gon' hate, @Cthulhu